# MYSQL group by with min value is returning the wrong row

Tags: mysql

I have the following table called market_listing
with the following columns:

| id | tokenId | price | resourceGroupId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Im trying to get the minimum price for each resourceGroupId and on the same query im looking for the tokenId which matches that minimum price.

For example

| id | tokenId | price | resourceGroupId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 27 | 500 | 1 |
| 2 | 25 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 300 | 2 |
| 8 | 5 | 200 | 2 |
| 9 | 8 | 100 | 3 |
| 4 | 13 | 150 | 3 |
| 5 | 15 | 750 | 4 |
| 6 | 27 | 900 | 4 |

If i use:
`SELECT resourceGroupId, MIN(price) as min_price, tokenId FROM market_listing GROUP BY resourceGroupId`

What happens is that on one side i do get the minimum price for a specific resourceGroupId, but the associated tokenId is wrong, i would get something like

| tokenId | price | resourceGroupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27 | 1 | 1 |

How can this behaviour be solved? Like when looking for the min price also get the values of that same row?
The expected result for this example would be:

| tokenId | price | resourceGroupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 200 | 2 |
| 8 | 100 | 3 |
| 15 | 750 | 4 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your could try this query

```
SELECT resourceGroupId, MIN(tokenId) AS tokenId, MIN(price) AS min_price 
FROM market_listing m1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1 
      FROM market_listing m2 
      WHERE m2.resourceGroupId = m1.resourceGroupId 
            AND m2.tokenId <> m1.tokenId
            AND m2.price < m1.price)
GROUP BY resourceGroupId
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NolPLOuI)

Comment: Hey Trung thanks for your reply,
If i do that, i will get multiple entries for each resourceGroupId,
I want to get the minimum price of each resourceGroupId and the associated tokenId of that record

Comment: I've updated the query, please check it.

Comment: Hey trung! Thanks again for the help!
I just tried it out, the problem with this one is that its ignoring the resourceGroupId GROUP BY
Im getting multiple records with the same resourceGroupId and price

Comment: We don't need to use GROUP BY, only using sub-query in `WHERE` statement. I've added demo, please check.

Comment: Yes, i meant that its not grouping by resourceGroupId , check this screenshot 
https://i.postimg.cc/tgxSzrp9/image.png

Im not getting the minimum price for each resourceGroupId, im getting multiple resourceGroupId

Its a though one this one haha

Comment: You've got multiple `resourceGroupId` because there are multiple rows with same min price. In that case, we could add `GROUP BY` to get row that has min price and min token id. Please check updated answer.

Comment: Seems like this one is working at least for the first result, but do you think it will always return the correct tokenId ? Cause according to mysql manual, when you do a group by, the other columns of that row are chosen randomly

Comment: It will always return correct token Id, since at the first step, we have filtered rows which have min price for each resourceGroupId, then at the second step, 'GROUP BY' and MIN will return min tokenId of each group returned by first step.